# HDMI Output Causes Streaming Media to Play Slowly

Tags: 16.04, sound, video, pulseaudio, hdmi

I've searched through several posts and haven't found one that seems to replicate what I have happening.

I'd like to stream video and audio (i.e. Youtube) from my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 to my TV. When first plugged in, the display is picked up automatically and runs just fine, but the audio still comes from the built-in laptop speakers. No problem, I just go into PulseAudio and select for audio to go through the HDMI port.

However, when I do this, it slows the video down to something like 0.5x speed. The audio through the TV is low and garbled, and the video, which was playing fine with volume coming from the laptop, is also playing slowly. Everything else is fine (scrolling doesn't become slow, just the video). I'm not very familiar with what sort of hardware, drivers, etc. are involved with this to know exactly where the problem is.

Any insight into how I could get both video and audio to play at normal speed through HDMI would be great!

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look like the same problem:  [Sound like half speed after suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1580882)

Try to upgrade to latest daily Alsa driver as shown here : [dkms Alsa HDA Intel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS)

You have to download package from [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages) : clic the arrow from   package   containing "xenial" in  its name, scroll down to "package files" , download .deb file  and install it using software manager or command line (`sudo apt-get install filename.deb`) , then reboot .

There are 2 Xenial packages: the first one in the list is more recent, may be better .

Answer (score 0):

MMM i'm a broadband user myself and Ive found a neet gimmick if you controls your through put on your device i use a rt 7000 nighthawk use 2 adapters and bounce your out traffic to a high powered router from your second adapter i have been operating 3 devices and 2 streaming t vs off of 3 to 6 mbps but you better have no bandwidth limits i burn 200 gig a month easy

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me, weirdly, was going into ~/.config/pulse and modifying the permissions of all the files in there.

e.g. `sudo chmod 755 *`

I imagine there's something in the config files that pulseaudio needed but applications running under my user were not able to access their contents? (just a guess, I really have no idea)